# What does "clone_fields" and "clone_model" attribute mean in vendor\magento\module-catalog\etc\adminhtml\system.xml?

Tags: magento2, product-images, system.xml

```
<group id="placeholder" translate="label" sortOrder="300" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
    <label>Product Image Placeholders</label>
    <clone_fields>1</clone_fields>
    <clone_model>Magento\Catalog\Model\Config\CatalogClone\Media\Image</clone_model>
    <field id="placeholder" type="image" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
        <backend_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Backend\Image</backend_model>
        <upload_dir config="system/filesystem/media" scope_info="1">catalog/product/placeholder</upload_dir>
        <base_url type="media" scope_info="1">catalog/product/placeholder</base_url>
    </field>
</group>
```

I have come across `source_model`, `backend_model` but this `clone_model` is seen the first time.

Answer (score 2):

[Reference Link](http://www.jyotiranjan.in/blog/how-to-create-custom-configuration-fields-for-magento/)

[Reference Link 2](https://suyati.com/blog/magento-custom-configuration-fields)

> **clone_fields** and **clone_model**:- These are use to Create Configuration field Duplicates with some Prefixes.
>
> clone_fields is a boolean and **clone_model** is the contains the
>   model class that should be used for retrieving the prefixes.The model
>   should contain `getPrefixes()` methods that will return an array of an
>   assocateive array that will contain all fields and label